# Eclipse plugin two classes in one view

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to merge two sub classes into one view in an Eclipse plugin. Is this possible to do in a plugin.xml. Or is there another way around it? I want to display them in a table view. This is an example of a plugin with one class:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
    <view id="com.example.myplugin.view"
          name="My View"
          class="com.example.myplugin.MyView:MyClass"
          icon="images/eview.gif"  
    />
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to have one main class for the view. That main class can make use of any number of other classes to help implement the view in the usual Java way.

Note: Your example extension point has a colon character in the `class` attribute - this is not allowed. The `class` attribute value is just the fully qualified class name of your view class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I put the question wrong. The colon character is apparently specific for our customization. I will remove this question as I've found out this solution I wanted to do is not possible.